# Using NIO vs RandomAccessFile to read chunks of files

Tags: java, nio, randomaccessfile

I want to read a large text file about several GBs and process it without loading the whole file but loading chunks of it.(Processing involves counting word instances)

If I'm using a concurrent hash map to process the file in parallel to make it more efficient, is there a way to use NIO or random access file to read it in chunks? Would it make it even more efficient?

The current implementation is using a buffered reader that goes something like this:

```
while(lines.size() <= numberOfLines && (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     lines.add(line);
}

lines.parallelStream().. // processing logic using ConcurrentHashMap
```

Comment: Make up your mind. Which is it? NIO? Or `RandomAccessFile`? In any case you can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader`. You're not going to get more than say 20% faster with NIO, and it will be *slower* with `RandomAccessFile`, as there is no buffering: and multi-threading it may make it worse, or not do anything at all, as the disk isn't multi-threaded. Do you really need to do this?

Comment: I'm considering more performance tweaks. So the current implementation is more efficient?

Comment: I would consider *less* performance tweaks. Just process the file line by line and forget the chunking and parallel streaming. It seems to me that I have already answered your final question. I certainly tried.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Still, have to do chunking since if the file is too large for the RAM right?

Comment: Wrong. If you process a line at a time the RAM size is irrelevant, unless you have really exceptionally long lines.

Comment: Understood. thanks

Comment: The obvious java 7 Solution is :  String lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).reduce((a,b)->a+b);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RandomAccessFile` makes only sense if you intend to "jump" around within the file and your description of what you're doing doesn't sound like that. NIO makes sense if you have to cope with lots of parallel communication going on and you want to do non-blocking operations e.g. on Sockets. That as well doesn't seem to be your use case.

So my suggestion is to stick with the simple approach of using a BufferedReader on top of a InputStreamReader(FileInputStream) (don't use FileReader because that doesn't allow you to specify the charset/encoding to be used) and go through the data as you showed in your sample code. Leave away the parallelStream, only if you see bad performance you might try that out.

Always remember: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I suggest you look up the entire quote. You might get a surprise.

Comment: @EJP "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." I don't see any surprises here, at least I doubt that this question falls into the 3% being mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

The obvious java 7 Solution is :

```
 String lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).reduce((a,b)->a+b);
```

Honestly I got no Idea if it is faster but I gues under the hood it does not read it into a buffer so at least in theory it should be faster

Comment: You guessed wrong. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-).